# Problema en ordenamiento de celda en matriz 5X5 por método Burbuja

Tags: c, ordenamiento

Tengo un proyecto de fundamentos de programación. Mi problema yace en el ordenamiento de columnas en el `case 5`, después de ordenar un par de veces las columnas (primeras 3 generalmente), empiezan a salir números negativos en las primeras celdas (posición cero) de esa columna siendo ordenada en el momento.

Programa de control de ventas:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void bienvenida (); //No recibe ni regresa datos
void menu ();//No recibe ni regresa datos
int opcion (int);//Recibe y regresa un valor
void solicitar (int);//No regresa pero sí recibe datos
int ordenar ();//Regresa pero no recibe datos

#define SIZE 5//Constante de tamaño de matriz

void main ()//Función principal
{
    int ventas[SIZE][SIZE]={0};
    int reng=0,col=0,op=0,valorC=0,option=0,valorS=0,hold=0,cont=0;
    bienvenida ();//Bienvenida de programa
    printf ("\n");
    srand(time(NULL));//Declaramos la función del sistema en random para poder utilizar la hora del sistema y calcular valores aleatorios
    do{
        menu ();//MENU de programa con opciones
        scanf ("%d",&op);
        option=opcion(op);
        switch (option)
        {
            case 1://Llenar matriz y columnas 2 y 3 con random
                printf ("\n");
                reng=0;
                col=0;
                while (reng<SIZE)
        {
                    ventas[reng][0]=(reng+1);
                    ventas[reng][1]=rand()%51;
                    ventas[reng][2]=rand()%501;
                    ventas[reng][3]=(ventas[reng][2]*ventas[reng][1]);
                    ventas[reng][4]=(ventas[reng][3]*1.15);
                    reng++;
                }
                break;

            case 2://Desplegar datos
                printf ("\n");
                reng=0;
                col=0;
                printf ("\nCOLUMNAS\n0: Vendedores\n1: No. de Articulos\n2: Precio\n3: Ventas Totales\n4: Ventas con Impuestos\n\n");
                while (reng<5)
                {
                    col=0;
                    while (col<5)
                    {
                        printf ("%d\t",ventas[reng][col]);
                        col++;
                    }
                    reng++;
                    printf ("\n");
                }
                break;

            case 3://Solicitar un dato
                printf ("\n");
                reng=0;
                col=0;
                valorS=0;
                printf ("Introduzca el renglon del dato a solicitar\t");
                scanf ("%d",&reng);
                if ((reng<0)||(reng>4))
                {
                    printf ("Renglon inexistente\n\n");
                }
                printf ("Introduzca la columna del dato a solicitar\t");
                scanf ("%d",&col);
                if ((col<0)||(col>4))
                {
                    printf ("Columna inexistente\n\n");
                }
                if (((reng>=0)&&(reng<=4))&&((col>=0)&&(col<=4)))//Validando valores en renglones y columnas
                {
                    valorS=ventas[reng][col];
                    solicitar(valorS);
                }
                else {}
                printf ("\n");
                break;

            case 4://Cambio de dato
                printf ("\n");
                reng=0;
                col=0;
                valorC=0;
                printf ("Introduzca el renglon de posicion del dato a cambiar\t");
                scanf ("%d",&reng);
                if ((reng<0)||(reng>4))
                {
                    printf ("Renglon inexistente\n\n");
                }
                printf ("Introduzca la columna de posicion del dato a cambiar\t");
                scanf ("%d",&col);
                if ((col<0)||(col>4))
                {
                    printf ("Columna inexistente\n\n");
                }
                if (((reng>=0)&&(reng<=4))&&((col>=0)&&(col<=4)))//Validando valores en renglones y columnas
                {
                    printf ("Introduzaca el nuevo dato a cambiar en la celda\t");
                    scanf ("%d",&valorC);
                    ventas[reng][col]=valorC;
                    printf ("El valor %d se ha introducido correctamente\n",ventas[reng][col]);
                }
                else{}
                break;

            case 5://Ordenamiento de columna
                printf ("\n");
                hold=0;
                cont=0;
                col=0;
                col=ordenar();
                //Validando valores en renglones y columnas
                if ((col>=0)&&(col<=4))
                {
                    for (cont=0;cont<SIZE;cont++)
                    {
                        for (reng=0;reng<SIZE;reng++)
                        {
                            if ((ventas[reng][col])>(ventas[reng+1][col]))
                            {
                                hold=ventas[reng][col];
                                ventas[reng][col]=ventas[reng+1][col];
                                ventas[reng+1][col]=hold;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else 
                {
                    printf ("Columna inexistente\n\n");
                }
                break;

            case 6://Salida de programa
                break;

            default:
                printf ("\n");
                printf ("Opcion Invalida\n\n");
                break;
        }
    }while (op!=6);//Ciclo de repetición de menu
    system ("PAUSE");
} //Fin de main


void bienvenida () //Función de bienvenida al inciar el programa
{
    printf ("BIENVENIDO AL PROGRAMA DE ADMINISTRACION DE ARTICULOS Y VENTAS EN UN NEGOCIO\nEste programa se encraga de facilitar la organizacion y el calculo en ventas en su negocio\n\n");
}

void menu () //Función que despliega las opciones del menú
{
    printf ("MENU\n1) Llenar matriz (columnas 2 y 3 con random)\n2) Desplegar datos\n3) Solicitar dato e imprimirlo\n4) Cambiar un dato\n5) Ordenar datos de de una columna especifica\n6) Salir\n");
}

int opcion (int opcionswitch)//Hicimos igualación de valores para poder cumplir con los tipos de funciones pedidas
{
    int opcions=0;
    opcions=opcionswitch;
    return opcions;
}

void solicitar (int solic)//Funcion que juega con los valores para conseguir el valor solicitado
{
    printf ("El dato solicitado es %d\n",solic);
}

int ordenar ()//Funcion que consigue el valor de la columna regresándolo
{
    int col3=0;
    printf ("Indique la columna a ordenar\t");
    scanf ("%d",&col3);
    return col3;
}
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a esta comunidad. Edita la publicación para que se vea bien. No hagas mucho uso de letras mayúsculas.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo, la seguiré. Empezaré a editarla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es que esto anda de milagro.. porque es c...

fijate que:

```
if ((col>=0)&&(col<=4))
            {
                for (cont=0;cont<SIZE;cont++)
                {
                    for (reng=0;reng<SIZE;reng++)
                    {
                        if ((ventas[reng][col])>(ventas[reng+1][col]))
                        {
                            hold=ventas[reng][col];
                            ventas[reng][col]=ventas[reng+1][col];
                            ventas[reng+1][col]=hold;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

en ese `for`, tu vas de la primer columna, que cuando pasas datos no esta bien porque usas `cont` para mover y `col` para cambiar datos de lugar, hasta el ultimo renglón, cuando no debería ser así porque tendrías que ir hasta el ultimo renglón - 1, porque el siguiente del ultimo renglón es un puntero a la nada misma.

Comment: Bueno, 'reng' es quien cambia de lugar los datos, 'col' sólo mantiene e identifica la columna a ordenar. Entiendo lo que quieres decir con respecto al intentar comparar con un dato que no existe, sin embargo, tengo un programa que fuciona de la misma manera utilizando un arreglo unidimensional, sin problemas. Entonces tu solución es empezar a la inversa o detener el for en 3? Muchas gracias! Me ayudo demasiado!

Comment: Igual tu algoritmo de ordenamiento tiene varios problemas. Para que usas cont entonces?? para hacer 4 pasadas?? de suerte ordena, el algoritmo de ordenamiento por burbujeo deberia ordenar hasta q no haga mas movimientos, no dependiendo de la cantidad de filas. Fijate que si quedo ordenado en cont 0, despues las otras pasadas no hacen nada.

Comment: Sí, lo entiendo, toma en cuenta que apenas llevo fundamentos de la programación. Me gustaría saber como poder lograr el ordenamiento total en una columna de 10000 datos (no lo digo como sarcasmo). Gracias por el consejo.

Comment: Wikipedia tiene una linda explicacion al respecto ;). pero no usaria un burbuja para eso.